# Second Linq filter for multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class (simplified) as follows:

```
class AppMeta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Scope { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a LINQ statement that properly filters results by cross referencing a list of integers, and discarding matches:

```
var hiddenApps = List<int>();
//populate hiddenApps
var listItems = List<rawdata>;
//populate listItems
List<AppMeta> apps = AppMeta.Collection(listItems).Where(i => !hiddenApps.Contains(i.Id)).ToList()
```

My question is, I need to further filter this list as follows,

`(Where Scope == "user" && Where User.LoginName == CurrentUser.LoginName)`

Can I still do that in one Linq statement, I.E. Can I combine that with my line above? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify multiple conditions in your `Where` clause. Modify your Where clause as:

```
.Where(i => !hiddenApps.Contains(i.Id) 
            && i.Scope == "user" 
            && i.CreatedBy.LoginName == CurrentUser.LoginName )
```

So your query would be:

```
List<AppMeta> apps = AppMeta.Collection(listItems)
                            .Where(i => !hiddenApps.Contains(i.Id) 
                                   && i.Scope == "user" 
                                   && i.CreatedBy.LoginName == CurrentUser.LoginName)
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: Looks great. As soon as I test it and the system lets me, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating another query, why don't you try adding those conditions to your `Where` method?

```
var loginName = CurrentUser.LoginName;
List<AppMeta> apps = AppMeta.Collection(listItems)
                        .Where(i => !hiddenApps.Contains(i.Id) && 
                                    i.Scope == "user" &&
                                    i.CreatedBy == loginName )
                        .ToList();
```

Just make sure that `CurrentUser.LoginName` type is `User`